# Pandas convert column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
    A
0   2017-04-17 00:00:00
1   2017-04-18 00:00:00
2   2017-04-19 00:00:00
3   2017-04-20 00:00:00
4   2017-04-21 00:00:00
```

I am trying to get rid of the H, M, S, so that I am left with:

```
     A
0   2017-04-17
1   2017-04-18 
2   2017-04-19 
3   2017-04-20 
4   2017-04-21
```

the dtype of column A is object. I have tried:

```
df['A'] = df['A']datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

with:

```
import datetime as datetime
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: How about `df['A'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`?

Comment: It is `df['A'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` but that contradicts your title. Are you trying to convert to datetime or convert to string?

Comment: What is current `dtype` of that column is it str or datetime64? Also what is it you really want is a str or still datetime without the time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) - output are `strings`:

```
#if necessary
#df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])

print (type(df.loc[0, 'A']))
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>

df['A'] = df['A'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print (df)
            A
0  2017-04-17
1  2017-04-18
2  2017-04-19
3  2017-04-20
4  2017-04-21

print (type(df.loc[0, 'A']))
<class 'str'>
```

and for dates use [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df['A'] = df['A'].dt.date
print (df)

            A
0  2017-04-17
1  2017-04-18
2  2017-04-19
3  2017-04-20
4  2017-04-21

print (type(df.loc[0, 'A']))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```