# Pandas 'astype' with date (or datetime)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648923/4288043) contains a very elegant way of setting all the types of your pandas columns in one line:

```py
# convert column "a" to int64 dtype and "b" to complex type
df = df.astype({"a": int, "b": complex})
```

I am starting to think that that unfortunately has limited application and you will have to use various other methods of casting the column types sooner or later, over many lines. I tested `'category'` and that worked, so it will take things which are actual python types like `int` or `complex` and then pandas terms in quotation marks like `'category'`.

I have a column of dates which looks like this:

```
25.07.10
08.08.10
07.01.11
```

I had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676152/pandas-convert-column-to-datetime) about casting date columns but none of them seem to fit into the elegant syntax above.

I tried:

```py
from datetime import date
df = df.astype({"date": date})
```

but it gave an error:

```
TypeError: dtype '<class 'datetime.date'>' not understood
```

I also tried `pd.Series.dt.date` which also didn't work. Is it possible to cast all your columns including the date or datetime column in one line like this?

Comment: How are you obtaining this dataframe `df`? If you are reading it through a CSV, you could simply use `dtypes` argument to explicitly set the `dtype` of every column.

Comment: Yes, am reading it from a csv. Maybe that is what you are supposed to do, put something into `read_csv` as you read it, but still one would think it would still be possible after and in one line.

Comment: I don't think there is a `date` `dtype` in pandas, you could convert it into a `datetime` however using the same syntax as - ```df = df.astype({'date': 'datetime64[ns]'})``` When you convert an `object` to `date` using ```pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date``` , the `dtype` is still `object`

Comment: `df = df.astype({'date': 'datetime64[ns]'})` worked by the way. I think that must have considerable built-in ability for different date formats, year first or last, two or four digit year. I just saw 64 ns and thought it wanted the time in nanoseconds. While 'date' types might exist, I get the impression from the docs that that type is perfectly suitable for dates https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This has been answered in the comments where it was noted that the following works:

```
df.astype({'date': 'datetime64[ns]'})
```

In addition, you can set the dtype when reading in the data:

```
pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
```

Answer (score 4):

#### datetime

Since you can't pass datetime format to `astype()`, it's a little primitive and it's better to use `pd.to_datetime()` instead.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

For example, if the dates in the data are of the format `%d/%m/%Y` such as `01/04/2020`, `astype()` would incorrectly parse it as `2020-01-04` whereas with `pd.to_datetime()`, you can pass the correct format.

If you need to convert multiple columns into datetime64 (which is often the reason `astype()` is used), then you can apply `pd.to_datetime()`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': ['01/04/2020'], 'date2': ['02/04/2020']})
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Even with `read_csv`, you have some control over the format, e.g.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['date'], dayfirst=True)
```

---

#### date

If you want to cast into `date`, then you can first cast to `datetime64[ns]` and then use `dt.date` to get a column of `datetime.date` objects:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
```

The column dtype will become `object` though (on which you can still perform vectorized operations such as adding days, comparing dates etc.), so if you plan to work on it a lot in pandas, it's more performative to use `datetime64` instead. For example, adding a day is extremely fast on `datetime64` columns, not so much on `date` columns:

```py
s_dt = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1700', None, 10000, 'D'))
s_d = s_dt.dt.date

%timeit x = s_dt + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
# 344 µs ± 17.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit y = s_d + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
# 56.1 ms ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

With that being said, if you dump it into a database (such as sqlite), an `object` dtype column of `datetime.date` objects stored as a DATE type (whereas `datetime64[ns]` will be stored as TIMESTAMP).

---

Pandas datetime dtype is from numpy datetime64, so if you have pandas<2.0, you can use the following as well (since pandas 2.0, unitless datetime64 is not supported anymore). There's no `date` dtype (although you can perform vectorized operations on a column that holds `datetime.date` values).

```py
df = df.astype({'date': np.datetime64})

# or (on a little endian system)
df = df.astype({'date': '<M8'})
# (on a big endian system)
df = df.astype({'date': '>M8'})
```

Comment: I did not think I could perform operations on the `object` datatype. Thats good to know. Thanks!